# jasmine IT block executes before 'beforeAll' block

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

In my node.js project in VSCode i am trying to read config info before i run the specs. But my specs are always executed first before my "beforeAll" block.

```
beforeAll(() => {
    console.log('Step0………..: ');
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log('Step1………..: ');

        browser.getProcessedConfig().then((config) => {            
            console.log('environment 12: ' );
            resolve(true);
        });    
    });
});

describe('*************************Executing TestSuite************************', function () {
    console.log('Step2………..: ');
    it("should support async execution of test preparation and expectations", function() {
        expect(3).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });   
});//describe
```

I tried simplifying the code to keep just one expect statement but still its the same.

The current output i get is Step 2 , Step 0 , Step 1

What i am expecting is Step 0, Step 1 , Step 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated output was correct as per jasmine documentation. The code in IT block won't be executed until beforeAll is completed. But if beforeAll has any promises then we need to pass done keyword to make the execution wait for beforeAll async operations to complete before executing IT blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your beforeEach function has within it asynchronous code: your Promise does not resolve before it begins running your first test.

[Jasmine has a utility to handle asynchronous behaviour](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)

If you pass a `done` parameter to your beforeEach call, you can then call this `done()` function within your promise resolution.
Taking your example here:

```
beforeAll( (done) => {
            console.log('Step0………..: ');
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                console.log('Step1………..: ');

                browser.getProcessedConfig().then((config) => {

                    console.log('environment 12: ' );
                    resolve(true);
                    done()
                });    
            });

        });

        describe('*************************Executing TestSuite************************', function () {

            console.log('Step2………..: ');

            it("should support async execution of test preparation and expectations", function() {
                expect(3).toBeGreaterThan(0);
            });

        });//describe
```

Comment: I ran the above code.It didn't work for me. It prints the old result.

Comment: Try without the nested `Promise` (just use the browser.getProcessedConfig), you shouldn't need to return a `Promise` from your `beforeEach`

Comment: Still didn't work. May be you can update your answer with working code.Thanks.